# How to convert keyword argument to named argument in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

1st file:

```
class Profile(object):
   def __init__(self, name, 1st_arg=gst(), 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=AB.parallel):
        self.name = name
        self.gain = 1st_arg(i, o, p)
        self.channel = 2nd_arg
        self.mode = 3rd_arg
```

2nd file:

```
class A:
   some_function():
     1st_arg = gst(i, o, p) # class gst constructor
     result = Profile(Name, 1st_arg, 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=Phase) # profile class constructor
```

I have above code, but i want to change "1st_arg" to named argument from keyword argument.

Here 2nd_arg and 3rd_arg arguments clearly specify to whom their values are being assigned, but not the same in 1st_arg.

I want this change so that if some 3rd party saw my code then he would understand it easily.

Comment: post the actual code. This is very unclear..

Comment: `change "1st_arg" to named argument from keyword argument` - keyword arguments are arguments given in the form `argument_name=value`. Positional arguments are the ones where you just give the value.

Comment: What do you mean by "named argument"?  The only thing I can imagine that meaning is the same as "keyword argument".

Comment: I want line to be chnage like this:  value = gst() 
   result = Profile(Name, 1st_arg = value, 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=Phase)

Comment: What's stopping you from using `result = Profile(Name, 1st_arg=value, 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=Phase)`, as you suggest? Or maybe you want the local variable to be called `1st_arg` rather than `value`? In that case you might be looking for `result = Profile(Name, 1st_arg=1st_arg, 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=Phase)`.

Comment: @BrenBarn i am referring named argument with this: "argument=value", i m not used to with python so i don't know actual terms

Comment: @MagnusHoff result = Profile(Name, 1st_arg=1st_arg, 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=Phase)  this gives me error, what else i need to change for the this line.

Comment: @Patrick: If it gives you an error, you need to edit your post to include the entire error message.  Also the `argument=value` form *is* a keyword argument.

Comment: @BrenBarn error is SyntaxError: non keyword argument after keyword argument

Comment: @Patrick: It's pretty clear you're not posting you're actual code, since `1st_arg` isn't even a valid variable name.  (Identifiers can't begin witha  digit.)  Please post actual code that you are running.

Comment: @BrenBarn after some hours i will post the actual code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a positional argument to a keyword argument (and it's the last keyword argument), just specify its name. For example, if you have a call of the following form:

```
f(val1, val2, arg3=val3, arg4=val4)
```

and you want to provide `val2` as a keyword argument, just call it like

```
f(val1, arg2=val2, arg3=val3, arg4=val4)
```

If the argument you want to convert isn't the last positional argument, you'll have to convert all following positional arguments to keyword arguments, too.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just change the argument from a keyword argument to a positional argument:

```
class Profile(object):
   def __init__(self, name, gst, 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=AB.parallel):
        self.name = name
        self.gain = gst(i, o, p)
        self.channel = 2nd_arg
        self.mode = 3rd_arg
```

You *had* a bigger problem, though. Calling a function in a method signature in Python only calls that function once, at compile-time. So, if you were noticing some unusual behavior related to `gst()` being in the method signature, that's why. If you pass a function reference as an argument, it can be called later. Don't call the `gst()` in the method signature itself, just pass it in as `gst`.

Edit: I think this is what you're after

```
class Profile(object):
   def __init__(self, name, 1st_arg=gst(sane, default, args), 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=AB.parallel):
        self.name = name
        self.gain = 1st_arg
        self.channel = 2nd_arg
        self.mode = 3rd_arg

value = gst(i, o, p)
result = Profile(Name, 1st_arg=value, 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=Phase)
```

Comment: Looks like you've interpreted the OP's desire in the exact opposite direction I did. Based on the following line, I think he wants to make the name of the argument explicit at the call site: "Here 2nd_arg and 3rd_arg arguments clearly specify to whom their values are being assigned, but not the same in 1st_arg."

Comment: @Oregon I want line to be chnage like this:  value = gst() 
   result = Profile(Name, 1st_arg = value, 2nd_arg=1, 3rd_arg=Phase)

Comment: Ok, so call `gst()` outside the constructor, and then pass in the return value. I'm not sure what the point of your question is.